# How to programatically clear Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to programmatically clear a Firebase realtime database. In the Firebase console, I know how to empty the database by clicking on the database name and hitting "clear", but how am I able to do it through Javascript? is there a `.clear()` or `.empty()` command for the database I can use in Vanilla JS?

Comment: You need to find the `end-point` first, then you should be hitting the API from your server.

Comment: @BasheerKharoti what relation does that have to my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Firebase Realtime Database empty, you can [delete its root node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data).

So something like:

```
firebase.database().ref().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call `remove()` on  the Reference that points to the root of the database, as follows:

```
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  rootRef.remove();
```